# How handle PATCH method in Flask route as API?

Tags: python, api, flask

I have this route:

```
@bp.route('coordinates/<int:id>/update', methods=['PATCH'])
def update_coordinates(id):
    schema = CoordinatesSchema()
    coords = Coordinates.query.get_or_404(id)
    new_data = request                           #????

    # some another logic
    return jsonify({"result": "GOOD"}), 200
```

I am passing a data for update in a body, like a dict: `{ "title": "newtitle"}` but I how can I get this info inside a route?

Comment: You could try a Flask extension called Flask-Restless that implements this. A complete working example is available on the [Flask-Restless documentation](https://flask-restless.readthedocs.io/en/stable/requestformat.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With PATCH requests you retrieve request data the same way you do for every other request type (e.g. POST). Depending on how you send your data, there are several ways to retrieve it:

Sending as `application/json`:

```
data = request.json
```

Sending as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (form data)

```
data = request.form
```

Sending as raw body with no `Content-Type` header:

```
data = request.data
```

The last one will give you a bytes string that you will then have to process accordingly. For your use case I suggest using the first example and add a `Content-Type: application/json` header when you send your PATCH request.